# An equality in the proof of Proposition 3 of Section 2.7 of Pierre Samuel's Algebraic Theory of Numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, trace, discriminant

I am reading Pierre Samuel's *Algebraic Theory of Numbers*. I get stuck at an equality within the proof of **Proposition 3** of Section 2.7. The statement of the proposition is as follows:

**Proposition 3.** *Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field that is either finite or of characteristic zero. Let $\mathbb{L}$ be an extension of finite degree $n$ of $\mathbb{K}$, and let $\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2},\cdots,\sigma_{n}$ be the $n$ distinct $\mathbb{K}$-isomorphisms of $\mathbb{L}$ into an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$ containing $\mathbb{K}$. If $(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$ is a base for $\mathbb{L}$ over $\mathbb{K}$, then*
$$D(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})=\det(\sigma_{i}(x_{j}))^{2}\neq0$$
*where $D(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$ is the discriminant.*

The proof starts with the definition of discriminant:
$$D(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})=\det(\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}}(x_{i}x_{j})).$$
The following equality confuses me:
$$\det(\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}}(x_{i}x_{j}))=\det(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sigma_{k}(x_{i}x_{j})).$$

I want to ask the following two questions:

*1)* I don't really understand how we reach the equality
$$\det(\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}}(x_{i}x_{j}))=\det(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sigma_{k}(x_{i}x_{j})).$$

My current guess is to use the following:
*For each element $y\in\mathbb{L}$, let $p(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $y$ over $\mathbb{K}$. Then*
$$p(x)^{\frac{n}{deg(p)}}=(x-\sigma_{1}(y))(x-\sigma_{2}(y))\cdots(x-\sigma_{n}(y))$$

Is this statment true? And why is it true or false?

If this is true, then I can get:
$$\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}}(x_{i}x_{j})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sigma_{k}(x_{i}x_{j})$$
as desired.

*2)* In the paragraph following the proof of this proposition, the author wrote

*The relation $D(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})\neq0$ means that the bilinear form $(x,y)\mapsto \operatorname{Tr}_{\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}}(xy)$ is non-degenerate.*

Why is this the case?

Comment: Very minor detail: in the book, are $Det$ and $Tr$ in italics? e.g., not as $\operatorname{Det}$ and $\operatorname{Tr}$?

Comment: @RobertSoupe Thanks for catching this. I have changed the italics so that the font matches up with the textbook. Do you have any hint or idea for this problem?

Comment: You're welcome. But I'm sorry, I have no idea on this problem. I have barely studied finite fields.

Comment: About your questions:

Comment: 1°.  Drop Det and look at the matrix. What's  written in each entry is just that the trace of an element, i.e. the sum of its conjugates, by definition
2°. This is a general theorem in the theory of bilinear forms for free modules over commutative rings, see any textbook (e.g. Lang’s « Algebra », subchapter « Duality »). A symmetric bilinear form over a finite dimensional vector space (at least in characteristic different from 2) always admits an orthogonal basis, i.e. the matrix of the form in this basis is diagonal, with only 1 or 0 on the diagonal. This gives you the criterion you cite.